# Rails jquery works for one but not the other

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have two checkboxes in a Rails form.

I'm trying to use Jquery (coffeescript) to force only one to be checked.

Here is my code:

```
  $('#costproject_rebudget').change ->
    alert 're-budget'
    checkbox = document.getElementById('costproject_rebudget')
    if checkbox.checked
      $("#costproject_new").attr('checked', false)

  $('#costproject_new').change ->
    alert 'new'
    checkbox2 = document.getElementById('costproject_new')
    if checkbox2.checked
      $("#costproject_rebudget").attr('checked', false)
```

Here are the fields from the browser:

```
<input checked="checked" class="boolean optional" id="costproject_rebudget" name="costproject[rebudget]" type="checkbox" value="1">

<input class="boolean optional" id="costproject_new" name="costproject[new]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

The `alert 're-budget'` works and the `alert 'new'` doesn't.

They look the same to me - and I can't figure out why one works and the other doesn't.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: [it's working for me](http://jsfiddle.net/vny9bzpy/)

Comment: check if costproject_new doesn't have another change bind

Comment: I searched the app and #costproject_new is only in the 3 places in the code above.

Comment: I'm using 3 forms each in a tab - I found that 2 forms had the costprojec_new - THANKS! ps. add an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if **costproject_new** doesn't have another change bind.

jQuery only permit one bind by pair object,event.